# I have two sets of RAM in an HP DC7800 but only one pair works at a time. I can’t get all four to be recognized

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have an [HP DC7800 convertible mini tower](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3459245) and it has [the following motherboard (HP 0AACh)](http://www.game-debate.com/motherboard/index.php?mot_id=1991&motherboard=HP%200AACh) (according to CPUz).

On page 5 of the specs it describes the product code which mine shows a 2.0 for the memory which is 2x2GB (which the PC came with). Page 11 shows the different specifications available with this model, mine was 2 x 2GB and shows a max memory of 8GB which is 4 x 2GB

I have 4 slots all with 2GB of DDR2 in but a [Crucual memory scan](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/scanview/A8DB4F7B31D926C3) only shows 2 slots and Windows and CPUz only recognise 2 slots.

Both sets of RAM work independently but not in a 4 config.

What could be up? the specs say 4 x 2GB but I only see 2 x 2GB in 2 different tools!

Comment: Do all 4 slots work independently? Do two sticks work in either pair of slots?

Comment: I believe so but would need to double check as it's a couple of weeks since I tested

Comment: A damaged socket or bit of debris in the socket (preventing contact) is a possibility. An improperly seated CPU is a possibility too (though less likely).

Comment: i think i need to strip it down and clean it out just in case, will give it a try

Comment: Last time I did this, HP had to give me a bios flash before it would recognize the additional ram. That was for a laptop, so may not be applicable, but you might be surprised to find they know exactly what you need to do. their chat support option is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can try:

1. Check the manual carefully. It is conceivable the 8GB config is only possible by 2x 4GB in stead of 4x 2GB.
2. Update the bios. Often a newer bios adds more supported RAM configs.
3. You have 2 pairs of RAM (the original and another one). If these pairs are not exactly the same DDR2 strips (different brand/different type-number) you have to make sure that you put each pair in the matching memory bank. Check the manual in which slots a single pair should be installed (It is not always slot 0 and 1. Sometimes the first pair must be in 0,2 or in 1,3 !!!).
   Place the original RAM there. And fill the other 2 slots with the
   other pair. (If you had a single pair consisting of mismatched DDR2
   modules working, that doesn't mean 2 pair work in arbitrary
   combinations. Typically there is more leeway in timing with just 1
   pair.)
4. If both pairs have different speed ratings (E.g DDR2-667 and DDR2-800) experiment with swapping the pairs around. Some motherboards prefer to have the slowest pair in the first slots, while other motherboards want the fastest pair there.

Comment: thanks for the reply,

I am not sure on 1, that's what I am trying to work out

scared to do 2 but will do it if I need too

can't see anything in the manual on #3 but will play around, they are current in 1&3, 2&4, when I bought the machine the initial RAM modules were in 1&3 so added new RAM to 2&4

4) Both are different manufacturers but same speed and type, I was meticulous in finding the right RAM.